# Unicode char has odd gap when rendered in view

Tags: swiftui, unicode

I am using the following code to show a playing card. Not sure why there is a large gap at the top.

This is on iOS 15.4

```
var body: some View {
    Text(String(Character(unicodeScalarLiteral: "\u{1F0A1}")))
        .font(.system(size: size))
        .foregroundColor(.red)
}
```

[image: playing card with gap above]

Compare to how this smiley is displayed:

[image: smiley without gap]

Comment: What do you mean by a large gap? Do you have a picture of how the code renders a different glyph correctly so we can compare? I would guess you have found a bug in the renderer so perhaps also reveal which OS exactly this is running on.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Please notice how I updated your question to make it self-contained; providing additional information in comments should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how this symbol layout within glyph box (pay attention on its position relative to base line):

[image: demo]

and here is for comparison of Latin A:

[image: demo2]

and really if both in one `Text`

[image: demo3]

Probably you just need different symbol/image, or try to use some manual workaround like

```
    Text("\u{1F0A1}")
            .baselineOffset(20)
```

[image: demo4]